# How do I maximize speed on a straightaway in Uniracers?

Tags: uniracers

The very first level of Uniracers is a complete straightaway. I always wondered what the best technique was to maximize speed.

The best I have found is to hold R to Roll, and tap A midway through jumping to Twist. With continuous jumping, I'd get 2 stunts per jump and go fairly fast.

Is there a technique to go faster than that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**My recollection was that your method:  Roll + Twist was the optimal one.**

**The reason you couldn't do better was that you were balancing the difficulty of the trick (which  added speed) against the cleanliness of the landing (which maintained it**).

I think I remember that the additional complexity you could get by adding a directional move, etc. sometimes made the landing too rough, so the increase in "trick boost" was more than offset by the "friction" on the landing.

Also, it's nice to know that I'm not the only one who remembers this game - I thought it was one of the best SNES titles that never really got famous.

Comment: Yes, that's the method I was referring to, but badly said, +1.